# lxc network type empty

Tags: networking, lxc

I want to run lxc machine without network.
I write in config file "lxc.network.type=empty" 
and boot instance image, but image not booting (hovered, freeze).
In documentation written that:

> empty: will create only the loopback interface.

So, what i need to do to boot machine without a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an unswer!
Go to **/etc/network/interfaces** and comment lines:

> ## auto eth0
>
> ## iface eth0 inet dhcp